# jQuery current-menu-item-highlight in tandem with js anylink menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

Example of relevant page - http://brettcolephotography.com/search.html

This page - "search" - is a dropdown item under "library" in my toplevel menu.

I"m using this snippet to highlight the current nav item, and it works great (thanks Joe!)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var loc = window.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, '');
    $('#bcp-nav a').each(function(index) {
        if(this.href.trim() == loc)
            $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

I'm also using the popular [anylink js](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/dropmenuindex.htm) menu script from Dynamic Drive to power the nav drop-downs.

**I would like to pass the currently-highlighted state onto the items in the submenu, such that in this case the "library" topnav item would be highlighted when you're on this search page.** I'd like to implement a structure such that I can apply to all similar cases.

Menu contents file code for this example

```
var anylinkmenuLIBRARY={divclass:'anylinkmenu', inlinestyle:'', linktarget:''} //Second menu variable. Same precaution.
anylinkmenuLIBRARY.items=[

    ["galleries", "http://brettcole.photoshelter.com/gallery-list"],
    ["search", "http://brettcolephotography.com/search.html"],
    ["advanced search", "http://brettcole.photoshelter.com/search-page"],
    ["lightbox", "http://brettcolephotography.com/lightbox.html"]
     //no comma following last entry!
]
```

and it hooks into the corresponding li, in this case

```
<li><a href="http://brettcole.photoshelter.com/gallery-list" class="menuanchorclass" rel="anylinkmenuLIBRARY">library</a></li>
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: I guess an easier and sufficient approach is just to give the li an id and write an underline style for it, and employ that style on just the pages in question. That's something I can do without making it any fancier than it needs to be. Still curious how to achieve this in a more automated fashion, but for my purposes doesn't seem like it's really necessary. Thanks

Comment: I've implemented my above fix, so the original example won't make as much sense if you now look at the page without taking this fact into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

In  `menucontents.js` change make the following changes:

```
anylinkmenuINDIA={divclass:'anylinkmenu'
// to
anylinkmenuINDIA={divclass:'anylinkmenuINDIA'

anylinkmenuPROJECTS={divclass:'anylinkmenu'
// to
anylinkmenuPROJECTS={divclass:'anylinkmenuPROJECTS'
```

and so on. Basically, make the `divclass` the same as the object name.
Then update `anylinkmenu.css` so that your new classes will be styled properly.
Line 14 would become:

```
.anylinkmenuINDIA, .anylinkmenuPROJECTS, /* your other classes here */ {
```

Then you can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var loc = window.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, '');
    $('#bcp-nav a, div[class^="anylinkmenu"] a').each(function (index) {
        if (this.href.trim() == loc) {
            var linkClass = $(this).closest('div').get(0).className;
            if (linkClass.indexOf("anylinkmenu") > -1) {
                $('#bcp-nav a[rel="' + linkClass + '"]').addClass("selected");
            }
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
```

This is now tested and working on your site.

Comment: Thanks again Joe, what do you think of using this vs my above approach, which is pretty simple since my site architecture is pretty simple. I just wrote a single underline style tied to the li id and put it in an external sheet. Then I can just include that sheet on any page that falls under that menu. I don't do much if any switching around of page placement, so it seems adequate. I did learn by looking at your example though, so thanks.

Comment: with your approach would I rewrite any of the li itself - <li><a href="http://brettcole.photoshelter.com/gallery-list" class="menuanchorclass" rel="anylinkmenuLIBRARY">library</a></li>

Comment: @Ursinus - sorry for the delay, I was fixing a few errors in my code. (Mainly this one: `var loc = window.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, '');` it's a corrected version of my previous approach). My solution isn't too hard to implement and it will mean you don't have to mess around including certain styles on certain pages to make sure things look right.

Comment: hmm, looks like I didn't do something correctly. I don't see any issues. Oh I'm replacing that part of the css, not appending the whole sheet? What about all those other properties, I'm needing to affect underlining only. I will try keeping existing properties and adding the underline.

Comment: I haven't done it properly if you wouldn't mind terribly any input is appreciated

Comment: I've just taken a look and here's how to fix it: put `anylinkmenu.init("menuanchorclass")` **above** the javascript code I posted. Then make sure your CSS looks like this: `.anylinkmenuPORTFOLIO, .anylinkmenuLIBRARY, .anylinkmenuINDIA{` on line 14 of `anylinkmenu.css`.

Comment: it's done but menus are gone now, bear with me, I really appreciate the help

Comment: It's no problem :-) just change this line `anylinkmenu.init("menuanchorclass")var loc = window.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, '');` to just `var loc = window.location.href.replace(window.location.hash, '');` and then I would advise moving all the code I wrote to the bottom of the page (just before `</body>`)

Comment: no luck, maybe I didn't do the css right, I tried to move this to chat but being new I can't

Comment: No problem (you don't have enough rep yet). I'll post an example for you.